# How to change all notification emails form one system admin profile to other system admin profile

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

In my company ,We have two system administrator profile .Previously it was only one system administrator he had created many email notifications batch ,workflows ,trigger ,apex class ,apex exception .

Every notifications form his mail id by default it will come .Now i has joined as one more administrator,He asked to change all his notification email form his mail id to my email id .

I has seen in batch apex, apex classes no where he has declared that mail has to go from his mail id .

Without changing his profile as system admin .How can i complete my task "change all his notification email form his mail id to my email id"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in classes email id is not hard coded.Probably there is a query which is retrieving the email id field or retrieving the value from custom setting record.There are lots of way to avoid the hard coded emailid.

**Try to check the code which sends mail notification and identify how the value of email id is provided.**
That way you would be able to change it.

Other less hectic way is to just ask the person ;)